A question about the smart pointer and deleter in C++ Boost Lib
I created a smart Pointer using Boost Lib :
boost::shared_array<int> spArray = nullptr;
Then, I let it manage a 16bit aligned memory:
spArray.reset((int *)memalign(16, 100 * sizeof(int)));
The code written this way did not encounter any errors.
A few days later, I read a Blog. It points out that the default deleter of smart pointer is delete, so I add a free deleter in my code：
spArray.reset((int *)memalign(16, 100 * sizeof(int)), free);
It also did not encounter any errors.
I was wondering if my code was correct?
The correct way to use the smart pointer deleters

The first version is definitely undefined, like the blog apparently says. "Seems to work" is one possible result (and not entirely unexpected if delete actually calls free on your system. It just doesn't have to work).

I would look into a custom (aligned) allocator. I didn't know it myself but apperantly C++ already hase one : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc. Or have a look at : C++ Smart Pointers with Aligned Malloc/Free

Unrelated, but unless you're using a compiler which doesn't support modern C++ standard, please use the standard C++ smart pointers. And unless you have very specific requirements, don't use smart pointers for an array, and instead use std::vector (or, depending on use-case, std::array).

The first way doesn't work on my system, because malloc, new, and new[] all have different arenas (i.e., different heaps).

I read the man page on memalign.  It appears the function you want is not the obsolete memalign, but rather the function posix_memalign that can be used with free.

The default deleter for shared_array is operator delete[], not operator delete anyways.

Thank you all for your comments. I read the source code，delete[]  is the default deleter for shared_array. It would be necessary to use free as the deleter. This is just an experiment. In actual work, if there is no specific need, I think not using smart pointers is also a viable option.
